# Adding Right Aligning Constraints to the Programmatically Added Subview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to add a right aligned Segmented Control to the `UITableViewCell like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "mycell")
    // ...
    addSegmentedControlToCell(cell)
    // ...
```

and then

```
func addSegmentedControlToCell(_ cell:UITableViewCell){
    let items = ["One","Two"]
    let unitControl = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    unitControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    let maxWd = cell.frame.size.width
    let maxHt = cell.frame.size.height
    let padding:CGFloat = 5
    unitControl.frame = CGRect(x:maxWd/2, y:padding, width:maxWd/2, height: maxHt-padding*2)
    unitControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SettingsTableViewController.unitControlValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    cell.addSubview(unitControl)
}
```

This works well on my default device iPhone 6. But when I run this app on a smaller width device, like iPhone 5, the programmatically added Segment Control, which receives 50% of cell width (cell.frame.size.width/2) seems much bigger that 50% of width and stretches to the right under the cell view port.

This is because of auto-layout and constraints as I see because iPhone 5 cell view gets resized. So I am trying to add a constraint to my new Segment Control, which fails with app crush. Note, I am not very good with programmatically adding constraints yet.

```
    let widthContr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: unitControl,
                                        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width,
                                        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal,
                                        toItem: cell,
                                        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute,
                                        multiplier: 1,
                                        constant: 0.5)
    cell.addConstraints([widthContr])
```

How to right align subview correctly (Segment Control) for correct cell size?

Answer (score 1):

You can set constraints like this:

```
yourView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourCell.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

Or:

```
yourView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

But make sure that you include this code:

```
yourSegmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 3 ways. 
1) You have written 0.5 constant in NSLayoutConstraint(this is a mistake).
You need to write constant is 1 and multiplier should be 0.5. 
2) Or you should update frame of UISegmentControl in layoutSubviews() method of Custom Cell.
3) Or you should write cell.layoutSubviews() after UISegmentControl adding to Cell.